# How to use nginx proxy_pass

Tags: node.js, nginx

How can I specify a url path in proxy_pass. Below is the nginx conf file

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com/
}
```

The url http://www.example.com/ will redirect dynamically to http://www.example.com/image/file.aspx?img=1

How to specify a url which internally redirect to another url. Any help on this will be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try the nginx [HttpRewriteModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule) you dont need a proxy for these(tho).
it follows this format:

```
rewrite regex         replacement                              flag
   |      |                |                                    |
rewrite   ^/    http://www.example.com/image/file.aspx?img=1 permanent;
```

Then:

```
location / {

    rewrite ^/ http://www.example.com/image/file.aspx?img=1 permanent;

}
```

Comment: When I hit the base url http://www.example.com/ in browser,it will dynamically append some extra parameters in the url http://www.example.com/image/file.aspx?img=1 to open the page.How can I configure in nginx such base url?

Comment: Dynamically append parameters will be hidden from the user.Base url will internally redirect to example.com/image/file.aspx?img=1

Comment: edit your question then. and put the code that you are trying